# Numpy slicing function: Dynamically create slice indices np.r_[a:b, c:d, ...] from array shaped (X, 2) for selection in array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, slice

## The situation

I have 2D array representing dual-channel audio. I want to create a function that returns slices of this array at arbitrary locations (e.g. speech only parts). I already know how to do it when I explicitly write the values into `np.r_`:

### Sample data

```py
arr = np.arange(0,24).reshape((2, -1))
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

### Input

A x length array of width 2. E.g.

```py
selector = np.array([[0, 2], [6, 9]])
# array([[0, 2],
#        [6, 9]])
```

### Desired output

```py
# create an indexed arrays
selection_indices = np.r_[0:2, 6:9]
# array([0, 1, 6, 7, 8])

# use indices to select 2D
arr[:, selection_indices]
# array([[ 0,  1,  6,  7,  8],
#        [12, 13, 18, 19, 20]])
```

## Goal

A function that takes a X length array of width 2 (shape: X, 2), representing the start and end of a slice, and use that to return a selection of an array. Effectively the `np.r_[0:2, 6:9]`, but then from an argument.

```py
arr = np.arange(0,24).reshape((2, -1))

def slice_returner(arr, selector):
    # something like this (broken); should be like: np.r_[0:2, 6:9]
    selection_indices = np.r_[[row[0]:row[1]] for row in selector]
    # return 2D slice
    return arr[:, selection_indices]

selector = np.array([[0, 2], [6, 9]])
sliced_arr = slice_returner(arr, selector)
```

How do I turn the input into selection slices? Preferably with minimal array creation / copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think boolean-indexing could be one efficient way. Hence, we can create a mask and then index cols and get our output -

```
# Generate mask for cols
mask = np.zeros(arr.shape[1],dtype=bool)
for (i,j) in selector:
    mask[i:j] = True

# Boolean index into cols for final o/p
out = arr[:,mask]
```

The memory-overhead is just the mask, which being a boolean array should be minimal and the final output, which is required anyway.

**Vectorized mask creation**

If there are many entries in `selector`, there's a broadcasting-based vectorized way to create the mask for cols, like so -

```
r = np.arange(arr.shape[1])
mask = ((selector[:,0,None]<=r) & (selector[:,1,None]>r)).any(0)
```

Comment: That's actually better than my solution.

Comment: @NilsWerner Yeah initially I was going with that concatenate method, but the final required output swayed me this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an indexing array from individual aranges

```
slices = [[0, 2], [6, 9]]
np.concatenate([np.arange(*i) for i in slices])
# array([0, 1, 6, 7, 8])
```

and use it to extract the data

```
arr[:, np.concatenate([np.arange(*i) for i in slices])]
# array([[ 0,  1,  6,  7,  8],
#        [12, 13, 18, 19, 20]])
```